# How to return multiple values from a function without global types

Tags: sql, oracle

In an application GUI-Elements can be initialized by using SQL statements.

```
SELECT name $GUIElement
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1337;
```

Since the underlying database structure may change, I am prefering to hide the structure and use an Oracle Package as interface instead. For single values this approach works well with functions like:

```
SELECT myPackage.getNameByID(1337) $GUIElement
FROM DUAL;
```

Now I am facing the issue of initializing a list. Original Code:

```
SELECT name $GUIList
FROM myTable;
```

To return multiple values from a function I need to define a new SQL type. If the function returns a `TABLE OF VARCHAR2` this code works:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE $GUIList 
FROM TABLE(myPackage.getNames())
```

Unfortunately, I have no rights to create new types on the productive database.
So, is there a way in Oracle to get a similar behaviour without defining a new data type? I have looked into `SYS_REFCURSER`but it seems not to work properly.

Comment: Why don't you set it up so the function always returns a table?

Comment: As far as I know, you need a new SQL type to return a table.

Comment: You can do that by creating a  Data Cartridge in PL/SQL. See e.g. here: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422 and here: https://github.com/method5/method4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about xmltype. The function always returns xml type. And for processing this object you are using xmltable.

Something like this.

```
create or replace function return_params return xmltype is
 result xmltype;
begin 

select xmlelement(params,xmlagg(xmlelement(param,xmlforest(name,value,data_type)))) into result from (
select 'param_name1' name, 'param_value1' value , 'varchar2' data_type from dual
union all
select 'param_name2' name, 'param_value2' value , 'varchar2' data_type from dual
union all
select 'param_name3' name, 'param_value3' value , 'varchar2' data_type from dual
);  return result;
end;

select * from xmltable('/PARAMS/PARAM' passing return_params 
                 columns name varchar2(1000) path 'NAME'
                         ,value varchar2(1000) path 'VALUE'
                         ,data_type varchar2(1000) path 'DATA_TYPE'
                 )
```

Comment: Very nice solution. I will wait a few days, and if nothing more elegant is proposed, I will accept your answer.